# How to enter in a unicode character code in BigQuery?

Tags: unicode, google-bigquery

Let's say I want to use the character `倀`:

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20480/index.htm

How would I type this into a query in BigQuery with the proper escape sequence? My thought was the following, but this seems like it's not correct based on the [Lexical Structure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#literals):

```
SELECT '倀', '\U00020480'
```

But obviously that's not correct as I'm getting:

[image]

How would I properly type it in with the escape code?

Comment: But then, 倀 is U+5000 https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5000/index.htm

Comment: 0x5000 (hex) = 20480 (decimal)

Comment: @qrsngky: Sure, but none of this is supposed to be in decimal.

Comment: @user2357112 If the OP was asking about Unicode character corresponding to hexadecimal 20480, that would be `` not `倀`. 
But since the OP specified `倀`, then that would be decimal 20480, which is 5000 in hexadecimal

Comment: @qrsngky: 20480 would be the right decimal representation of the code point, but none of the places where "20480" shows up in the question (either in the `\U` escape or the fileformat.info URL) are supposed to be in decimal.

Comment: @user2357112 Right, both the URL and the escape expect a hex value. I think the OP had somehow mistaken a decimal value for a hex, and could have solved the problem simply using a hex of `5000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below "hint"

```
SELECT '倀', CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([00020480])
```

with output

[image]